# Receiving "curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)" when adding payload to Google Cloud functions via http firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, api, curl, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send a payload to my endpoint using curl but I keep getting the response

> curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

when I add a body. If I send no information, I get back the expected result.

I am currently using

```
curl -X GET https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/<function> -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"name":"Jane"}'
```

with the appropriate project-id and function to as per [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). When I remove the  `-d '{"name":"Jane"}'` flag and payload, I get the appropriate response.

I am wondering what I might be overlooking here. To me it looks like an issue with the way I'm sending it, not the actual backend code, although I can provide some backend code if needed to help with this.

Comment: HTTP GET requests do not have an HTTP body. Change **GET** to **POST**.